# error documents and .htaccess file

Tags: php, .htaccess

what is the right format for .htaccess file and if there any example with error document in php? Thanks in advance fellas

this i have now

```
ErrorDocument 404 /pagenotfound/
ErrorDocument 400 /pagenotfound/
ErrorDocument 401 /pagenotfound/
ErrorDocument 403 /pagenotfound/
ErrorDocument 500 /pagenotfound/
```

Answer (score 0):

That's basically the correct syntax, although I'm pretty sure the target needs to point to an actual file, not a directory. Try having it point to a file instead.

[Apache documentation on ErrorDocument](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#errordocument)

Comment: Thanks pal, and could you please tell me how to find the error number it produces, using php.

Comment: @Kmanikandan I'm not sure whether that is possible at all. I don't know. In the worst case, you'd have to use separate files for each case